# Pagination in .Net Core PartialView

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, pagination, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Partial View in which I load a pager for pagination.

The functionality of the pagination works, as the link changes as follows: `http://localhost:1048/Trip` -> `http://localhost:1048/Trip?page=2` but it seems like my "request" to load the "next page" doesn't work as intended.

## PartialView

```
//Here is a table view that 
//that requires pagination.

@{ 
    var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : ""; 
}

<ul class="pager">
    <li>
        <a asp-action="Index"
           asp-route-page="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
           class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled btn">
                Previous
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a asp-action="Index"
           asp-route-page="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
           class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled btn">
                Next
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I assume that my link is wrong (asp-action="Index"), but I have no idea what else to have it "navigate to" (I tried changing it to my controller function - but that result was very much unwanted) as I am still fairly new to .Net. Also I know that I have an error in my Controller function where I load page 1 always. How do I check whether a page is input to the function? (something like `if (page == null) { page = 1 }`) The function that loads my Partial View is as follows:

## Controller function

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> TripTable(int? page)
{
    var trips = from t in _tripcontext.Tripmetadata select t;

    page = 1;

    int pageSize = 20;
    return PartialView("PartialTripsView", await PaginatedList<Tripmetadata>.CreateAsync(trips.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(t => t.Tripid), page ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

## UPDATE

I guess I forgot to mention that whenever I use the *Next* button it just refreshed the entire Index page (without the Partial View in it). The Partial View is loaded when a button on the Index page is clicked, so when the page refreshes the Partial View is not present anymore.

Comment: If you are doing redirect you need to rerender the whole page you can't return a partial view unless javascrip is involved. Your action need to have the name Index and the render the partial view inside the main page.

Comment: So do I need to create a new "Index" function?

Comment: Well you should already have an Index action in the controller just add an optional parameter `int page = 1` this will mean that if you don't send it will show the first page.

Comment: I see. Please see my update above. I will try adding the parameter to my index function.

Comment: My guess is that you used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page) tutorial as a starting point. As you can see the controller has an action Index and it just returns the page in the response. If you want only the grid portion to be rendered you need to use ajax. asp-index just creates a hyperlink to a different page.

Comment: That is true. I used that tutorial. And yes I get the part about the Index.

So I guess what I need to do is to create an ajax function that loads the next page whenever the next or previous button is clicked? Something like `$("#next").click(function() { /*something with ajax*/ });`. I don't have much experience with ajax. I have mostly used `jquery.load()` - But I guess it could be that `jquery.load()` is performing an ajax call for me behind the facade. I honestly don't know.

Comment: And I guess I would have to remove the `asp-action` part of my view?

Comment: Yes load dose an ajax call just call your partial with next page number and load it in your container.

Comment: I am unsure on how to pass the "url" to the load function. My `PaginatedList` model contains `PageIndex` so I can get the page number by doing: `$("#next").click(function() { var newPage = @Model.PageIndex + 1; $("#TripPartial").load( /* some url */});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out after quite some reading online:

First of I changed my PartialView to the following:

```
@{ 
    var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : ""; 
}

<ul class="pager">
    <li>
        <a id="prev" data-url="@Url.Action("TripTable", "Trip")" data-id="@Model.PageIndex" class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled btn">
            Previous
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="next" data-url="@Url.Action("TripTable", "Trip")" data-id="@Model.PageIndex" class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled btn">
            Next
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If someone else is stuck on the same problem I got most of my code from the Microsoft Docs on creating a pagination [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page).

My controller method was changed only a little:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TripTable(int? page)
{
    var trips = from t in _tripcontext.Tripmetadata select t;
    int pageSize = 10;

    return PartialView("PartialTripsView", await PaginatedList<Tripmetadata>.CreateAsync(trips.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(t => t.Tripid), page ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

And in the bottom of my PartialView I added the following:

```
<script>
    $("#prev").click(function () {
        var _this = $(this);
        var prevPage = _this.data('id') - 1;

        $("#TripPartial").load(_this.data('url'), { page: prevPage }, function () {
        });
    });

    $("#next").click(function () {
        var _this = $(this);
        var nextPage = _this.data('id') + 1;

        $("#TripPartial").load(_this.data('url'), { page: nextPage }, function () {
        });
    });
</script>
```